# Proof of simple inequality using only fundamental axioms

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

I want to prove that the solution set to the inequality $$5-x^2<-2$$ is $\ (-\infty, -\sqrt{7})\cup(\sqrt{7}, +\infty)\ $ using only the following axioms/statements (some of them have been put on the same line to keep it short):

1. Associative law (for addition and multiplication)
2. Existence of additive identity and existence of multiplicative identity
3. Existence of additive and multiplicative inverses
4. Commutative law (for addition and multiplication)
5. Closure under addition and closure under multiplication
6. Distributive law
7. Trichotomy law and definition of $\ <,\ >,\ \leq,\ \geq$
8. Definition of squaring ($x^2$) and square root
9. [Derived from 1-6] $\; a < b \Longleftrightarrow a+c<b+c$

Here is my (failed) attempt:

$$5-x^2<-2 \quad \stackrel{(9)}\Leftrightarrow \quad 2+5-x^2+x^2<2-2+x^2 \quad\stackrel{(1,3)}\Leftrightarrow \quad 7 < x^2$$

At this point I already wasn't sure how to continue. The only thing that occurred to me was:

$$7 < x^2 \quad \stackrel{(7)}\Rightarrow \quad x^2 \neq 7 \quad \stackrel{(8)}\Leftrightarrow \quad x\neq \sqrt{7}\ \land \ x\neq -\sqrt{7}$$

So now we know that the solution set S is a subset of $(-\infty, -\sqrt{7})\cup(-\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{7})\cup(\sqrt{7}, +\infty)$, but I don't know how to prove (explicitly using one of the previous 8 assertions at each step) that no $\ x\in(-\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{7})\ $ satisfies the original inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $\;x^2>7\iff\sqrt{x^2}=|x|>\sqrt 7$.

Comment: I thought of this as well at first, but nowhere in the starting assumptions is there a statement along the lines of $a<b \Rightarrow f(a)<f(b)$. And there's no concept of functions either, so we can't say that $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is monotonically increasing as a justification...

Comment: You have the concept of a square root, and you can prove $a<b\implies \sqrt a<\sqrt b$ by contrapositive from $ c\ge d\implies c^2\ge q^$, which results from first principles.

Comment: That's right, I didn't know that. Sorry about that.

Comment: Could you please show me or point me to somewhere where I can learn how $\ c \ge d \implies c^2 \ge d^2 \ $ from the first principles?

Comment: This depends how you define, say, `>`, but usually, you have a set $P$ such that $P\cdot P\subset P$, $\mathbf R=P\cup\{0\}\cup(-P)$ and these 3 sets are a partition of $\mathbf R$, and you define $a>b$ as $a-b\in P$. You then show easily that $a>b$ and $c\in P \Rightarrow ac>bc$. Last step: $a>b\Rightarrow  a^2>ab$ and $ab>b^2$, so by transitivity, $a^2>b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Presuming that $(5)$ includes the axiom of multiplicativity: $a \le b$ and $c \ge 0$ imply $ac \le bc$, $$0 \le x \le \sqrt{7} \stackrel{(5)}\implies x^2 \le \sqrt{7}x \stackrel{(5)}\le \sqrt{7}\cdot \sqrt{7} = 7.$$